# Laravel share session same domain as a module

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

I have a problem with the session share with my 2 laravel projects. My first project is portal.blabla.test and my other project is billing.blabla.test.

Portal is the authentification.
Billing is a module loaded inside portal.

I load the billing module inside portal project using ajax and i can't make the session share. Auth::check() doesn't work.

But, if i load the page manually in my browser (billing.blabla.test), i am logged in. It seems there is some issue when integrating my module inside another laravel project sharing the same auth.

I added cors for cross website sharing, i try sending the csrf token on the ajax call, i try changing the value 'same_site' in session.php for "lax".

I did this for both projects inside session.php using session_driver database:

```
  return [
    //...
  '   domain' => '.blabla.test'
  ];
```

Here is how i load the module :

```
   $.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    url: "https://billing.blabla.test/billing",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#content-module').html(data);
    }
   });
```

This is my page being loaded :

```
  {{ Auth::check() }}
```

I see an empty page when the module is loaded but when going https://billing.blabla.test/billing, i can see '1'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a wildcard subdomain to your session.php config's file, like that :

```
<?php

return [
  //...
  'domain' => '.blabla.test'
];
```

Like that you can share your session between subdomains :)

Comment: Hi, forgot to mention, i did that, both laravel projects are ".blabla.test"

Comment: I am also using SESSION_DRIVER=database to make this works.

Comment: any ideas? please